# issue integrating flex with ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, apache-flex

I'm having an issue integrating flex with ruby on rails. I get this error:

```
ActionController::InvalidAuthenticityToken (ActionController::InvalidAuthenticityToken):
  <internal:prelude>:8:in `synchronize'
  /Users/tammam56/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.1-p378/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpserver.rb:111:in `service'
  /Users/tammam56/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.1-p378/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpserver.rb:70:in `run'
  /Users/tammam56/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.1-p378/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/server.rb:183:in `block in start_thread'
```

I believe Rails automatically generate an AuthenticityToken when using "View" components that generates the HTML as I notice in the console AuthenticityToken gets passed with every request. But When I'm using Flex as my client interface instead of HTML generated by view how do I get/generate this AuthenticityToken and store it in Flex.

Thanks,

Tam

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hey, great question.  This was actually a pretty tough problem to solve, but Dima and contributors from [RestfulX](http://wiki.github.com/dima/restfulx/restfulx-framework-and-rails-21) have solved it quite nicely.

In short, you have to store the authenticity token in Flex after the *first* request Flex makes to Rails, right when everything starts up.  Then you pass it back with every request from Flex to Rails.  To get the request, RestfulX has an initializer script that gets in there with the Rack middleware to send the authenticity token to Rails.

I suggest checking out the [RestfulX Google Group](http://groups.google.com/group/restfulx-framework/browse_frm/thread/94275b1d964e4247/c939c8dffb97f0a6?lnk=gst&q=authenticity+token#c939c8dffb97f0a6), and checking out the sample [Pomodo on Rails](http://github.com/dima/pomodo_on_rails) application (RestfulX integrating Flex and Rails).  It's a serious Project Management Flex app with an Admin system, so check out the code for all that authentication stuff.

It was built off a script like this one:

[FlashSessionCookieMiddleware](http://gist.github.com/237741)

And here's a [tutorial explaining file uploads between Flex and Rails](http://jetpackweb.com/blog/2009/10/21/rails-2-3-4-and-swfupload-rack-middleware-for-flash-uploads-that-degrade-gracefully/), which have a lot of issues with authenticity tokens.

Let me know how it goes!
Lance

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a flex specialist but here is how you store in a js variable:

```
window._token = '<%= form_authenticity_token %>';
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a blog post on it that describes all the steps in how to do it.

See at:

http://blog.dt.org/index.php/2008/06/rails-2-flex-3-and-form-authenticity-tokens/

Hope it helps